# 2d convolution: What is the difference between convolution using blocked Toeplitz matrix and convolution layers?

Tags: convolution, neural-network

For a given matrices $A$ of size $4\times 4$ and $B$ of size $3\times 3$ then I construct a blocked Toeplitz matrix and perform the convolution. The resulting output is of size $6 \times 6$.
I have no doubt in setting up the blocked Toeplitz matrix and perform the convolution.

But in Neural networks the convolution of a $4 \times 4$ matrix with the so called kernel of size $3 \times 3$ results in $2 \times 2$ matrix. Presumably without zero-padding and stride of one.

I have no problem in understanding the results but the difference in output size is something I do not understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The former is calculating a full sized convolution resulting in an N + M - 1 size, while the later is probably calculating a "valid" sized convolution. This case only returns the values from the convolution where there is complete overlap between the matrices, resulting in an N - M + 1 size. See [MATLAB's documentation on the `conv` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html#bucr8kb-1-shape) (specifically the `shape` parameter) for more.